# clear dropdown values before form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I tried lot of posts but none seem to work for me.

I have 2 drop downs inside same form element and they should work in toggle manner, with following properties:

1. selecting any drop down should clear the other one and auto submit the form.
2. Also on form submit I am retaining the value of selecting drop down to display user what value had been selected.

For auto submit I have used .change and fformid.submit.

But issue is if i selected dropdown 1, form get submitted and page is displayed with dropdown1_value 1 selected and now when i make selection of 2nd drop down, both fdropdown 1 and dropdown 2 value gets submitted.

I tried using dropdown2_id.remove(), .emtpy(). .val("").

All these seem to visually remove elements, but form gets submitted with the value previously selected.

And i dont want to use Ajax, since I am using Django, doing Ajax will return result to js which is difficult for me to render than using html itself.

Comment: Can you please post your code.

Comment: don't just describe all these elements in text...show them to us as along with all relevant code. See [mcve]

Comment: Share code what you tried

Comment: Note that in order to deselect any value in a dropdown, you'll need to have an "empty" option.